# AWS API Gateway: Documentation Swagger export model type null ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I am having an issue while exporting AWS's API Gateway documentation to Swagger.
I have a documentation part for a JSON Schema model with null types such as:

```
{
  "title": "Incident",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "type": ["string", "null"]
    }
  }
}
```

It's working well for validation has it allows me to send null value for the updatedAt field. However in this case when I export my documentation to Swagger I only have this is my swagger file:

```
{
  "title": "Incident",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "id"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

My updatedAt field is simply ignored, I have the same issue if I set

```
"type": "null"
```

It is really problematic as I need to be able to send null values and in this case my swagger documentation is missing some fields in the model.

Is there any way to define a type in JSON Schema that won't be ignored by AWS API Gateway but that will still allows me to send null values ?

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT]

Turns out the *"nullable": true* solution doesn't fit in this case.
API Gateway seems to use OAI V2 and doesn't support *nullable*.
However when we export the model to Swagger (which in this case use OAI V3), we loose the null type. In conclusion I need to find a solution for null types that works with both OAI V2 and V3.

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

While JSON Schema supports the null type, the OpenAPI specification (previously Swagger) does not.

> Primitive data types in the OAS are based on the types supported by
>   the JSON Schema Specification Wright Draft 00. Note that integer as a
>   type is also supported and is defined as a JSON number without a
>   fraction or exponent part. null is not supported as a type (see
>   nullable for an alternative solution). Models are defined using the
>   Schema Object, which is an extended subset of JSON Schema
>   Specification Wright Draft 00.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#data-types

In stead, you use an additional property if you wish to be nullable, of `"nullable": true`, as per https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#fixed-fields-20

The "Schema Object" defined by OpenAPI is a subsuperset of JSON Schema.

Comment: Turns out the "nullable": true solution doesn't fit in this case. API Gateway seems to use OAI V2 and doesn't support nullable. However when we export the model to Swagger (which in this case use OAI V3), we loose the null type. In conclusion I need to find a solution for null types that works with both OAI V2 and V3.